# GPPSignInButton not loading GooglePlus.bundle when using storyboards

Tags: ios, ios7, google-plus, uistoryboard

Using Google+ SignIn for iOS SDK v1.4.1, I have a button of class `GPPSignInButton` placed in a view in a storyboard. It is connected to a `GPPSignInButton` outlet. `GooglePlus.bundle` has been added to the project and is copied into the app bundle and can be loaded (programmatically) from within the app at runtime.

When I run the app, either on a device or in the simulator, the button is blue.

[image]

I would expect it show a red *Sign-in with Google+* button. **Creating the button programmatically results in a button that displays correctly**. Inspecting the subviews of button instantiated via the storyboard and those of the programmatically created button shows that the storyboard button is missing a `UIImageView` instance.

The `-ObjC` linker flag is set. I've even tried adding `-all_load` with no effect.

I suspect there is a bug in `GPPSignInButton`'s `initWithCoder:`. Can anyone confirm or reproduce this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The solution was to set the button type to `Custom`—a step missing from the Google documentation.

Comment: Please file a bug for inaccurate docs: https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/list

Comment: @abraham Filed as [Issue 720](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=720).

Comment: But its showing bydefault button of Google+, not showing my button

Comment: Good god thank you I was hunting that down all afternoon.  Google really should specify this.

Comment: More detail: it is in right bar of "Identity Inspector section"

Comment: Realy healped Thanx @neilco